# voxel smoothing on sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I have imported this 3D model from a voxel editing application and used the sketchup tool "soften edges" with 180deg angle between normals and both "smooth normals" and "soften coplanar" enabled. It can be easily recreated by just putting together some cubes and follow the soften procedure I wrote above. Here is a picture of what I have so far.
[image: soft voxel]

What I was trying to achieve with the soften tool, was to have the edges and hill zones not to look like steps from a stair. However it didn't work as expected.

I then tried a plugin for terrain erosion, but the results were quite similar, as it seems the plugin keeps the original structure.

Now, I know that the inverse process, from a high resulution model to a voxelated one is relatively easy to do, as there is a loss of information, however, how would one do the opposite way? Is there an automated way to do it, or I have to resort to some other tool? If so, can anyone point me towards the right way of doing this?

Comment: From some research, I could find some useful info here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351605/how-to-smooth-the-blocks-of-a-3d-voxel-world

Does anyone know of any plugin that already has this or a similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In non-sketchup tools, or in SketchUp with a plugin called [**SUbD**](https://extensions.sketchup.com/en/content/subd), you can use [**subdivision surfaces**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) to achieve what I think you're looking for.

Subdivision surface modeling relies on all quad poly base cage modeling, so you'd also need the appropriate quad-modeling SU plugin, called [quadface tools](https://extensions.sketchup.com/en/content/quadface-tools).

[More general sub-d Explanation](http://hakenberg.de/subdivision/enclosed_volume.htm)

I use [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) as my 3D tool of choice, and it excels at sub-D modeling, in which one forms boxy base cages and subdivides them either on the fly or manually to achieve the most natural results in the least polygons.

These images show the relationship between the base polycage and the subdivided poly surfaces which result from them - hopefully this will give you a direction to explore.

[image]

For me working in modo, I use multi-resolution meshes some of the time, which is something you can do in a dedicated sub-D DCC tool like modo or maya, which has certain advantages for game asset modeling, for example.

https://help.thefoundry.co.uk/modo/index.html#help/pages/sculpting/multires_pallette.html%3FTocPath%3DSculpting%7C_____7

[Video - Sculpting w subDs](https://player.vimeo.com/video/127583969)

I think Sub-D's will be the best way to do what you are asking for.